# Bash - hide terminal arrow keys ("^[[A")

Tags: bash, arrow-keys

I wrote the following bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

coordx=0
coordy=0

while true; do
    read -r -sn1 t
    case $t in
        A) 
            ((coordy--))
            tput cup $coordy $coordx
            printf "test"
        ;;
        B) 
            ((coordy++)) 
            tput cup $coordy $coordx
        ;;
        C)
            ((coordx++))
            tput cup $coordy $coordx
        ;;
        D) 
            ((coordx--))
            tput cup $coordy $coordx
        ;;
    esac
done
```

It moves the terminal cursor when arrow keys are pressed. However, when the keys are held down, the following happens:

[image: gif]

At random intervals, the terminal code for each of the arrow keys is displayed. How can I hide these so that the terminal doesn't display them but is still able to print out content?

Comment: This will always happen, as the ncurses code (tput) is trying to keep up with the keyboard  buffer. What is the output from `stty speed`.

Comment: `stty speed` outputs 9600

Comment: you can try `stty -echo` (remember to restore it when the script exits)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

> ```
>  -N nchars    return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless
>               EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any
>               delimiter
> ```

Read all 3 characters of the arrow keys:

- ↑ <kbd>ESC</kbd>[A,
- ↓ <kbd>ESC</kbd>[B,
- → <kbd>ESC</kbd>[C,
- ← <kbd>ESC</kbd>[D

```
    read -r -sN3 t
    t="${t:2:1}"
```

Played a bit expanding your code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

typeset -i \
  coordx=0 coordy=0 \
  pcoordx=0 pcoordy=0 \
  cols=$(tput cols) lines=$(tput lines)
typeset -i \
  maxcol=$((cols - 1)) \
  maxline=$((lines - 1))

while true; do
  read -r -sN3 t
  case "${t:2:1}" in
    A)
      ((coordy > 0 ? coordy-- : 0))
      if [ $pcoordy -ne $coordy ]; then
        tput cup $coordy $coordx
        pcoordy=$coordy
      else
        tput bel
      fi
      ;;
    B)
      ((coordy < maxline ? coordy++ : lines))
      if [ $pcoordy -ne $coordy ]; then
        tput cup $coordy $coordx
        pcoordy=$coordy
      else
        tput bel
      fi
      ;;
    C)
      ((coordx < maxcol ? coordx++ : cols))
      if [ $pcoordx -ne $coordx ]; then
        tput cup $coordy $coordx
        pcoordx=$coordx
      else
        tput bel
      fi
      ;;
    D)
      ((coordx > 0 ? coordx-- : 0))
      if [ $pcoordx -ne $coordx ]; then
        tput cup $coordy $coordx
        pcoordx=$coordx
      else
        tput bel
      fi
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I copied this script, and only changed the -N to -n to be macOS compliant, and it still occasionally output the `^[[A` characters.